# A third person singular of phrase with fire

Tags: verbs, third-person-singular

Sentence:
You see a car in the street **fire** two shots at the person, who was standing on the sidewalk.
Source: [*One man shot and killed during gathering of Trump supporter](https://www.npr.org/2020/08/30/907619252/1-man-shot-and-killed-during-gathering-of-trump-supporters-in-portland)
It seems like **a car** is a third person singular of phrase, but **fire** isn't **fires**. Is it correct? Why is it happen?

Comment: cars don't fire shots. Guns do. Shots can be fired out of a car through the window. Anyway: You see x fire. fire is an **infinitive**. It is not: He fires a shot.

Answer (score 1):

The quote is from speech in an interview, and the speaker isn't speaking carefully. As the comment points out, cars don't fire shots. The expression should have been

> You see someone in a car fire two shots at the person...

That said, the question is the same. "Someone" is a third-person singular noun. Why isn't  the verb "fires"?

Let's simplify the example:

> He saw someone fire a shot.

The words "someone fire a shot" form a bare infinitival clause. It is the complement (object) of the verb "saw". That kind of clause uses the *bare form* of the verb, that is, the verb has no inflection for tense or number, and it is not preceded by "to".

This kind of clause is mentioned here:
[Wikipedia "infinitive"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitive)

> The bare infinitive form is a complement of the dummy auxiliary do, most modal auxiliary verbs, **verbs of perception like see, watch and hear (after a direct object)**, and the verbs of permission or causation make, bid, let, and have (also after a direct object).

Here are some other examples of verbs of perception followed by infinitival clauses:
I heard her *come* through the door.
I saw him *drive* the car away.
I watched the building *crumble* in the earthquake.

Comment: You see someone in the car* fire two shots....

Comment: Why does the edits not work for less than six characters? I mean I have seen moderators edit my post for only a two-letter word. Do they have special rights?

Comment: I don't know, but I fixed the word. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh It may have something to do with [rep](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit).

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty No Problem.

Comment: @Lawrence I see. Sounds okay now. Thanks!